# Sustainable text in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have input text field and I have a placeholder inside. When I click on input, placeholder disappears. I am using jQuery Watermark plugin for this placeholders. I want to change this behavior. I need that placeholder to stay in input when user types in this field.

Nice example would be field for e-mail. In one step, user gives me domain name, for example 'foo.com'. Placeholder for e-mail will look like '@foo.com'. When user clicks on this field, I want this placeholder to act like value of that input, but unchangeable. Default value of my e-mail input field is '@foo.com', when user types in 'bar' its 'bar@foo.com'.

I hope you understand what I am trying to do :) How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: After that would it be assumed everyone is `@foo.com`, or will many have to move the cursor past `@` to change to their service?

Comment: I dont want the @foo.com to be changed, when user clicks on input, cursor should be before @. The foo.com is unchangeable.

Comment: I think this would cause an usability issue; even if technically possible, it may lead to confusion, it should be **clear** for users that @foo.com is unchangeable. I think it's way better and more transparent to put it **outside** the textbox as normal text.

Comment: I was bored. It should look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EhvE9/). If it doesn't, as Cranio said, it'll probably confuse users.

Comment: Use a single text field with a static `@foo.com` label to the right of it. Don't attempt to do this all in one text field, it will look awful, work terribly and confuse everybody who tries to use it.

Comment: Why don't you just put "@foo.com" to the right of the text field and append it when you read the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have a absolutely positioned label for this. Also, you could handle onclick and onblur events on the input in case you want to hide the label. Try this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div style=" position:relative;z-index:1;">
                <label style="position:absolute; line-height:28px;text-align:left;left:150px;top:4px;overflow:hidden; height:28px;width:200px; z-index:2;color:#cacaca" for="email">@foo.com</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="email" style="border:1px solid #939393; line-height:28px;text-align:left;font-size:14px;padding-left:5px;color:#000;z-index:1;width:300px;height:30px" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate, it isnt exactly what I wanted, but it helped me :) I took your solution and added javascript, which will move left position of label when user types in new char. And I set font to monospaced one, so I can increment position easily :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function. I have used it once in my code (with help from stackoverflow) :

html:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" placeholder="@foo.com">​
```

javascript:

```
function setRange(input, textStart, textEnd) {
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(textStart, textEnd);
    }
else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', textEnd);
        range.moveStart('character', textStart);
        range.select();
    }
}
function setCursorPos (input, pos) {
    setRange(input, pos, pos);
}

$("#t1").click(function() {
    $(this).val("@foo.com");
    setCursorPos(document.getElementById("email"), 0);
});
```

Comment: Can be improved: selecting all the text using ctrl+a shouldn't select foo.com if i understood what OP wants correctly.

Comment: This solution is nice, but it isnt what I ment. In this case '@foo.com' can still be deleted by Delete key and clicking on input produce bad results

Comment: Then put a check on onBlur event of text box, if @foo.com is not there add one at the end.